# Is there any other software that can make PPT except libreoffice impress?

Tags: software-recommendation, lubuntu, lxde, libreoffice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Light easy to use Presentation software](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58009/light-easy-to-use-presentation-software)

I'm running lubuntu now, which uses lxde as its desktop manager. LibreOffice Impress seems a little not compatible with lxde. So I want to find another software that can substitute it. Can anyone suggest anything?

Comment: what do you mean by "a little not compatible"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 'fossfreedom' said, it would be nice to know what doesn't seem to be compatible.
Cause maybe you can sort things out easily.

But if you want to try alternatives I would recommend trying "Calligra Stage". You can install it from the software center.
Or if you want it a little more lightweight and you have a good internet connection you could use GoogleDocs to create your presentation and install the "PowerPoint Viewer" from software center to view your presentation offline.

Hope this helps out.

Answer (score 1):

Well, There are many programs to make Presentation [OpenOffice](http://www.openoffice.org/), [KOficce](http://www.koffice.org/download/),[GnomeOffice](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeOffice) and Microsoft Office !

you can run Microsoft Office 2007 under wine with no problems, as my friend said.

Hope it Helps.